# Inconsistent behavior with apex:dynamicComponent

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dynamic-visualforce

I'm trying to migrate some code over to using dynamicComponents to avoid some XSS vulnerabilities and it's not working how I would expect it to when inside any type of repeat functionality (`apex:repeat`, `apex:pageBlockTable`)

**Reproducer**

```
public class CompTest {
    class InnerClass {
        public Component.Apex.OutputText getDynamicComp() {
            Component.Apex.OutputText comp = new Component.Apex.OutputText(escape = false);
            comp.value = '<b>test</b> test';
            return comp;
        }
    }

    public InnerClass singleComp {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<InnerClass> compList {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CompTest() {
        this.singleComp = new InnerClass();
        this.compList = new List<InnerClass> {
            new InnerClass(),
            new InnerClass()
        };
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
<apex:page controller="CompTest">
    <h1>Single Comp</h1>
    <br />
    **<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!singleComp.dynamicComp}" />**

    <br />
    <h1>Comp List</h1>
    <br />
    <apex:repeat value="{!compList}" var="comp">
        **<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!comp.dynamicComp}" />**
        <br />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

*Visualforce*

**Output**

[image: Visualforce Output]

This looks like a bug to me, but I'd like to know if anyone has seen this before, or if I'm missing something in the documentation that says you can't use the `apex:dynamicComponent` inside a looping tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by setting the `invokeAfterAction` attribute on the dynamic component in the repeat.

`**<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!comp.dynamicComp}" invokeAfterAction="true" />**`

Comment: That works great.  Any idea if this is how it's suppose to work or just a "work around"?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the order of how things are rendered in the page. invokeAfterAction changes that order. There's more on it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_deferred_creation.htm) but I don't see anything directly relevant.